# Clarification needed about WCF Concurrency in REST Services

Tags: wcf

I have created WCF Rest services. When i am hitting the same request continuously  from client(i.e from Android mobile) it is using diifrerent threads and thread.sleep is also not working.

My code is  below like this..

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "VerifyLogin")]
        public bool VerifyLogin(Login loginCred)
        {
            bool res = false;
            string strThreadPrint= "";
            try
            {
               strThreadPrint= Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "  time at : "+DateTime.Now;
               Thread.Sleep(5000); 
               dbcon = new DBConnection();
//for testing here i am throwing an exception so that its going to catch block and responce sent back to client with exception details as shown in catch block.
               dbcon.VerifyLogin(loginCred.Username.Trim(), loginCred.Password.Trim()); 
            }
            catch (Exception sqlex)
            {
                objErrorClass = new ErrorClass("Login class", sqlex.Message + " --- " + strThreadPrint, "CNMK");
                throw new WebFaultException&lt;ErrorClass&gt;(objErrorClass, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            }
        }
    }
```

when i am sending request using fiddler with following 
`Requestbody` `{"Username":"13","Password":"dgdf"}`

At that time i am getting the responce as in Json format

```
Response from service:

{"ErrorDesc":"login failed --- 33 time at :09/04/2013 12:31:30"}
{"ErrorDesc":"login failed --- 35 time at :09/04/2013 12:31:30"}
{"ErrorDesc":"login failed --- 41 time at :09/04/2013 12:31:30"}
{"ErrorDesc":"login failed --- 45 time at :09/04/2013 12:31:30"}
```

So the instance mode and concurrency mode not working for wcf restful services????
or am i doing any wrong in my code?? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have WCF host a single instance of the service operation and then have the service wait 5 seconds before responding?

If that is so then you should use the InstanceContextMode.Single, which will mean that all service requests will be routed to the same instance of the service for processing.

**EDIT**

I don't understand what behavior you want to see. You have 4 concurrent requests, you have a per call service instance, you will have all 4 requests processed at the same time by 4 different service instances. I cannot see what the problem is with your output.

**EDIT2**

ConcurrencyMode will determine how EACH INSTANCE of the service deals with concurrent requests dispatched to THAT INSTANCE.

However, you are specifying an instance PER CALL. You have 4 calls, therefore you will have FOUR INSTANCES of the service with the net result that each call will be processed concurrently.

So the behavior you are observing is completely correct for the way you have configured your service.

If you want a single service instance to process all your calls then you need to specify InstanceContextMode.Single.

Comment: no hugh... I have applied the same technique as i read in this article
**[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and)**

Comment: So what is the behavior you want to see?

Comment: My question is even i mentioned the ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single my thread is not sleeping. 
I have tried to with InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession also but the thread is not sleeping.

Comment: Hugh, If we decorate a class with  ConcurrencyMode = Single in serviceBehavioutr then how many threads created for the concurrent requests? If we decorate with Single then only one thread will enter into that process and after that thread work completed then only another thread will be enter. But in my scenario what happens?? the threads are created differently and executed at the same time. But it will not happen if we decorate ConcurrencyMode with single.

So that i am asking "instance mode=percall,persession and concurrency mode is not working for wcf restful services???"